# Turing decider Halting Problem

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

Wiki and my classes Textbook defines a decider as:

> In computability theory, a machine that always halts—also called a
>   decider (Sipser, 1996) or a total Turing machine (Kozen, 1997)—is a
>   Turing machine that halts for every input.

So shouldn't this decider be able to decide the Halting Problem?
Because it halts always? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a decider:

> On input $w$, accept if $|w|$ is even, and reject if $|w|$ is odd.

Does it solve the halting problem?

Comment: no, you want to imply that there is no decider for the halting problem?

Comment: You claimed that a decider should be able to decide the halting problem. However, this decider doesn't decide the halting problem. In fact, Turing proved that no decider can decide the halting problem.

Comment: ok then my understanding of  a decider was wrong @Yuval Filmus very nice could I hire you? I have a lot of more questions :D